# Unexpected "authentication switch request" while connecting to MariaDB instance

Tags: c#, mariadb

So, I'm writing some C# code to follow the client server protocol to connect and modify a database. I've gotten it to work with MySQL, and I'm adapting it for MariaDB.

(Using this: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connection/)

The connection sequence is failing for both an AWS MariaDB instance, and a local one on my machine. My steps are:

1. connect via TCP, and I get an initial handshake packet that looks as expected, gives me scramble data and specifies an authentication plugin of "mysql_native_password".
2. I reply with a client handshake response packet (not using SSL) in which I encode client capabilities, the encrypted password (using SHA1( password ) ^ SHA1( seed + SHA1( SHA1( password ) ) ), which worked with MySQL), and specifying the auth plugin "mysql_native_password"
3. I receive back an 0xFE "authentication switch request header", in which it specifies a plugin name of "mysql_native_password" and new plugin data.

This is confusing, because that isn't a switch, we were already using mysql_native_password! I guess I'm a little confused by the concept of a "switch"... does this happen because there is some problem in my client handshake response packet (which I've triple checked), and it is asking me to try again? Why would I get this response from MariaDB?

Thanks for any insight!

Update: per request, here is a google sheet that shows the packet data, from the initial handshake through the unexpected auth switch request.  It's a simple local MariaDB server with root/password as the login.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_qa0aXc--FYCl6cSu33kpqwfs6lHPlD5OVOuYsRJMfo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The are more than one type of authentication method.  Your server and client both have PLUGIN_AUTH.  In this case switch in not just inside the application.  There are windows and network settings that determine the authentication method that can be used.  Read the ELSE in the connecting paragraph in your link.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code or a tcpdump. Can you capture the connection handshake with wireshark and provide a link to the dump? Also the client response packet needs to contain max_packet_length and user name (which aren't mentioned in your post).

Comment: @GeorgRichter, I've added a link to the packets received, sent and received via google docs... hopefully that works?  I've annotated and color coded, that would be awesome if you spotted the error.  Thanks!

Comment: @Chris: The first choice when debugging client/server protocol is to use wireshark, since his dissector supports MySQL client/server protocol but also most of the MariaDB extensions.

Comment: Packet length and packet number are missing. I wonder how this worked when connecting to a MySQL server. But without a tcpdump as already requested probably nobody wants to assist.

Comment: MariaDB uses a slightly different password encryption algorithm than MySQL. In MariaDB, the encrypted password is calculated using SHA1(password) XOR SHA1(seed + SHA1(SHA1(password))), where seed is the scramble data sent by the server in the initial handshake packet. Make sure that you are using this algorithm to encrypt the password before sending it in your client handshake response packet.